# How do I enabled syntax highlighting for Jasmine/ Protractor code in VSCode Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jasmine, protractor, syntax-highlighting, uiveri5

How do I enabled syntax highlighting for Jasmine/Protractor/UIveri5 code in VSCode Windows?

[No syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx2Rf.jpg)
[With Syntax Highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJbc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install these two vscode plugins:
[JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sourcegraph.javascript-typescript)
[Jasmine code snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.JasmineSnippets).
Double check your file extension (should be .js) and the language mode in the lower right of the editor (should be JavaScript)